# How to overlay a component on top of another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement a floating action button and I want to overlay it on other pieces of a component but in anyways it goes under the other components, even when I try to implement it in the parent component.

I want to implement it from material UI [Floating action button](https://material-ui.com/components/floating-action-button/)

Here is what I've tried before:

```js
const fabstyle = {
        margin: 0,
        top: 'auto',
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        color:'green',
        left: 'auto',
        position: 'fixed',
};
return (
    <div >
        <Fab style={fabstyle}></Fab>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are multiple ways to achieve this one is with grid,
the other which is simpler is making your parent component relative (position: relative) and the children component absolute (position: absolute).

Then you can position the children element with the values: **top, left, bottom* and *right*

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.children {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

In the example above, the children will be rendered in the top left corner of the parent component

Comment: I saw the same result with this approach

Comment: take a look at this codepen. https://codepen.io/GiulioBadger/pen/mdrjgKy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `z-index` property in the CSS class

Usage:

```
.myBoxOnTop {
    z-index: 3;
}

.myBoxOnBottom {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your parent component Position Relative & child component Position Absolute.
It will enable you to position your child element the way you want.

```
#Parent {
position: relative;
}

#Child {
position: absolute;
//Set the top,left,bottom & right properties the way you want to style your component
}
```